# How to convert class to persistent entity in hibernate with composite key

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I have class named 'User'
it having following properties

```
firstname
lastname
mobile
email
pin
```

I want module it to persistance entity with following constraint mobile and email will be unique for each user and atmost one of them will be null.I should be able to fetch record with email,with mobile and both email and mobile. Can it be possible using single persitence entity or i should divide this into two?

Comment: Refer to following link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9764204/how-to-create-a-composite-primary-key-hibernate-jpa

Comment: i tried using @EmbededId with (email,mobile) as the key...but it will not allow me to fetch records with email only..or mobile  only